# how to make buttons same width and float near the center?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a div row because I need them to be also the same width. I've google and there is not much help. I've tried changing the css using `.btn-row.btngroup{ width: some width;}` and still does not work!

Here is my code part :

```
   <div class="btn-row">
     <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Edit</button>
      </button>
     </div>

   <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Delete</button>
    </button>
   </div>


  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Add Service</button>
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is what it needs to look like
[image: Image 1]

This is what mine looks like
[image]

Also, how do I make the last button blue? The examples from twitter don't really show much

Thanks and really appreciate it!

Comment: which event must change button's background color?

Comment: put all buttons to another div and set style:

<div style="margin-left:100px;"> your buttons </div>

Answer (score 2):

To make the button blue, add the 'btn-primary' class.

To make them the same width, add a new class to each button (not the group) and define the 'width' of that class to whatever you want.

```
.my-btn { width: 150px; }
```

Comment: both you and Vikas combination answers gave what i want.I wish i can give 2 green checks!

Answer (score 2):

To make buttons float near the center just add

```
margin: 0px 0px 0px 100px;
```

or

```
margin-left:100px;
```

in class `btn-row`

Comment: both you and SCott combination answers gave what i want.I wish i can give 2 green checks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="btn-row">
     <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Edit</button>

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Delete</button>

         <button type="button" class="btn active btn-default ">Add Service</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-row{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn{
    border-radius:5px;
    width: 35px; /* You desired width*/
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: #fff;
}

.btn.active
{
    background:#488FE1;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #488FE1;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQQ6d/6/)

Comment: You can see that the trick is the width:100% and text-align:center in the parent div, therefore all the content inside will center